# How to run Python GUIS at startup (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, automation, startup

I am currently developping a selenium project and want it to always start the selenium Browser after Login, but by trying to put the script into /etc/profile it just gave me an error on startup:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

Is there any way to automatically run a python script at startup which can display things on the screen?
If yes how is this achievable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found just found it out on myself! The solution was to load the User interface before running any scripts. loading the interface is done by putting `su -l pi -c startx` at the verry beginning of the first sh script.put the whole command into /home/*username*/.profile

Answer (score 0):

create a sh script to lanche your programe, i don't have selenium on my maching (Ubuntu 18.04)i test it with a simple browser Firefox
crate a scipt sh and save it ander

```
/etc/profile.d
```

for example my script

`#!/bin/bash
firefox&`

Comment: I tried it, seems not to be working, Selenium is not starting even though I can run a browser and it gets displayed except for the selenium browser, any Idea?

Comment: tell us exactly what you did, and what did you wrote in /etc/profile.d/